# Email Activity log of SendGrid shows Delivered but no email received in the mailbox

Tags: java, smtp, sendgrid

I have been using SendGrid for sending email from java using the SMPT Host, Username and Password. I had created send grid SMTP using Azure. It has been working fine and emails were received in the mail inbox. However now when I am sending the emails, it shows as Delivered in the EmailActivity at URL https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity?

However, no emails are received in the inbox of email. I am using one Gmail id as the sender and another Gmail id as the recipient but it was working fine earlier.

What can be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Sendgrid have problems sending mail to Microsoft/Outlook/Hotmail users. This may help sometimes https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/